# SQL remove duplicates from results

Tags: sql

```
select DAC.LocationCode, DAC.Description, ReqApp.Rank, App.Approver as UserName,
CASE WHEN app.Approver = app.AlternateApprover THEN '' 
ELSE AltApp.AlternateApprover END As AltApprover, 
ISNULL(CONVERT(Varchar,AltApp.FromDate,101),'')AS FromDate,
ISNULL(CONVERT(Varchar,AltApp.ToDate,101),'')AS ToDate
from tblAPAlternateApprovers App
INNER JOIN tblAPAlternateApprovers AltApp
ON App.ID = AltApp.ID
INNER JOIN tblAPReqLocations DAC
ON App.tblAPReqLocationsID = DAC.ID
INNER JOIN tblAPReqApprover ReqApp
ON App.Approver = ReqApp.Approver AND 
App.tblAPReqLocationsID = ReqApp.LocationID
ORDER BY DAC.LocationCode ASC, ReqApp.Rank asc
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLbnj.jpg)

When SQL Adds an 'alternate approver' (for purchase orders), it creates an additional record for the actual approver. So, trying to find a way to show only 1 record for those approvers that also have alternates. i.e. 'jlhayes' has 2 records. One with an alternate and one without. For these records, I want to only see the ones that have an alternate.Thank you for your help. I've spend a couple hours and out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap `AltApprover` case statement in `max(AltApprover)` and group by `DAC.LocationCode, DAC.Description, ReqApp.Rank, App.Approver` and do similarly for `FromDate` and `ToDate`:

```
select DAC.LocationCode, DAC.Description, ReqApp.Rank, App.Approver as UserName,
max(CASE WHEN app.Approver = app.AlternateApprover THEN '' 
ELSE AltApp.AlternateApprover END) As AltApprover, 
max(ISNULL(CONVERT(Varchar,AltApp.FromDate,101),'')) AS FromDate,
max(ISNULL(CONVERT(Varchar,AltApp.ToDate,101),'')) AS ToDate
from tblAPAlternateApprovers App
INNER JOIN tblAPAlternateApprovers AltApp
ON App.ID = AltApp.ID
INNER JOIN tblAPReqLocations DAC
ON App.tblAPReqLocationsID = DAC.ID
INNER JOIN tblAPReqApprover ReqApp
ON App.Approver = ReqApp.Approver AND 
App.tblAPReqLocationsID = ReqApp.LocationID
GROUP BY DAC.LocationCode, DAC.Description, ReqApp.Rank, App.Approver
ORDER BY DAC.LocationCode ASC, ReqApp.Rank asc
```